# How to dual boot fresh install windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 with a BIOS?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, bios

I'm currently installing windows 8.1 on my laptop to take up the whole partition. While that's being set up I want to see how I can dual boot ubuntu 14.04 LTS with it. My computer has a BIOS so UEFI shouldn't be a problem.

Any tips on what I can do? I'm very excited to start learning linux and getting on a good solid UNIX base for programming. Any help on how to dual boot would be so helpful.

Comment: Just like any BIOS dual boot. But with Windows 8, you still need to turn off fast boot or always on hibernation. And use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition, but do not create any partitions with Windows. And reboot immediately after resize so it can run chkdsk and repair itself. http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Answer (score 0):

If you want Windows to take up the whole partition, you can install Ubuntu on a USB stick (that is large enough) **from within Windows** 2GB minimum if you don't plan to save data to it.

Download Pen Drive Linux's USB Installer

1. Select 'Ubuntu' from the dropdown list.
2. Click 'Browse' and open the downloaded ISO file.
3. Choose the USB drive and click 'Create'.

[Official documentation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)